# Controlling Creativity and Irrelevant Information in LLM Contextual Response

Tags: openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, large-language-model, llama

I'm using RetrievalQA from LangChain to create a chat model with 'llama v2.' While the responses are relevant to the context, it often adds a significant amount of creative content that isn't directly related.

For example, when I ask questions about framework documentation, the answers often include examples that partially relate to the provided context but also contain information from the model's own programming knowledge, which can be completely irrelevant to the context.

Here are the parameters I'm using to load the model:

```
'repetition_penalty': 1.15
'temperature': 0.1
'top_p': 0.15
```

And this is the prompt template I'm using:

```
[INST]<<SYS>>
You will be given a context to answer from. Be precise as possible in your answers.
Also make sure you following these rules while answering the question:
- In case you are sure you don't know the answer, then you say that based on the context you don't know the answer.
- In all other instances, you provide an answer to the best of your capability.
- Use examples only if you asked for.
- You don't use examples that are not in the context.
- You will never ask questions.
- You will never answer a question if the context is missing.
- Make the answer three sentences maximum and keep it as concise as possible. 
<</SYS>>
The context:
{context}
Given the context that has been provided, Answer the following question:
{question}[/INST]
```

I have already ensured that the context contains all the necessary information to answer the question.

What steps can I take to enhance my control over the model's responses? Should I make adjustments to the parameters, modify the prompt, or are there other strategies I can employ to ensure the answers are more tightly related to the provided context and reduce unnecessary creativity?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should have very well-defined prompt Role for your use case

```
[INST]<<SYS>>
As an AI assistant you provide answers based on the given context, ensuring accuracy and brifness. 

You always follow these guidelines:

-If the answer isn't available within the context, state that fact
-Otherwise, answer to your best capability, refering to source of documents provided
-Only use examples if explicitly requested
-Do not introduce examples outside of the context
-Do not answer if context is absent
-Limit responses to three or four sentences for clarity and conciseness

<</SYS>>
Context:
{context}
Given the provided context, answer:
{question}[/INST]
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548636/is-there-a-way-llm-answers-only-based-on-the-context-and-also-in-the-users-aske

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches for controlling the responses from the LLM, some include:

- Use LangChain's prompt templates to add context to a prompt, as you've mentioned that you're using here. It's possible to create your own prompt template or use ones that have been well-received (e.g., Chain-Of-Thought prompting).
- LLM guarding (input/response) is good for additional security. This approach can be especially useful as a guardrail for moderating responses from an LLM, so that the responses don't reveal sensitive information.
- Adjusting parameters for the model, such as temperature, n_batch, last_n_tokens, max_tokens, n_ctx, repeat penalty, top_p, and top_k, is crucial. Based on the model's architecture, each parameter instructs the model for specific tasks. For example, the context window size (n_ctx) limits the context of the model when it's trying to reason and generate responses. Temperature controls the randomness of the model's response. Top_p helps generate diverse and interesting responses. Top_k limits the number of likely words the model can choose from when generating a response. Repeat penalty discourages the model from repeating the same words or phrases too often, etc.
- Use a ReAct architecture for LLM responses (e.g., Langchain agents). This way, you can incorporate tools such as Langchain Tools like Wikipedia or Calculator as chains to help the LLM not only reason but also reason and take action. The LLM can then observe something from an action, for example, by using a calculator on a prompt like "what is 1 + 1" and observe that it is 2, and reason based on that.
- Incorporate context from external sources (e.g., RAG techniques), not solely relying on the prompt and prompt template. This approach proves highly efficient when used with LangChain's RetrievalQA. Furthermore, you can establish a threshold for the similarity score when matching with the prompt on external sources. This allows the LLM to be directed to perform different actions based on the similarity score, such as returning a different response or changing context if the similarity score is less than 0.5.
- You can also employ more classical pre-processing methods (e.g., using techniques from a frameworks like SpaCy) or sanitize prompts and responses for the LLM.

In any case, you'd want to first check the architecture of the model you're using. Some models are fine-tuned towards specific tasks, such as QA (e.g., Llama2-Chat from Meta), and others are tailored for stuff like function calling (e.g., Gorilla from UC Berkeley). Then, it would be very useful to try to understand the task of the LLM and the type of responses it should generate. For example, should the LLM generate more fun and less serious responses? Or should the responses have a low threshold for hallucinations? Questions such as these can be helpful in determining the implementation.