# Is there a way llm answers only based on the context and also in the user's asked language (Vertex AI)

Tags: openai-api, langchain, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am using Vertex AI from Google as my cloud model with langchain.

Requirement:
We're trying to build a chatbot system for arabic speaking users. The bot should answer questions only from the context and should not give random answers on it's own.

Please find the code below:

```py
embeddings = VertexAIEmbeddings()
db = FAISS.load_local(folder_path=constants.MODEL_DB_SAVE_PATH,
                        embeddings=embeddings, index_name=constants.MODEL_DB_INDEX_NAME)
retriever = db.as_retriever(search_type=constants.MODEL_SEARCH_TYPE, search_kwargs={  "k": 5 })

llm = VertexAI(
    model_name="text-bison@001",
    max_output_tokens=500,
    temperature=0.2,
    verbose=True
)
template = """You are a chatbot assistant for the ABCD (also known as Any Body Can Dance) festival. Your name is Sara, and your purpose is to provide warm and gentle responses strictly related to the ABCD festival. Please refrain from answering anything not related to the festival or its context. In case of a question in Arabic, respond in Arabic language  by converting your answer from English to Arabic.

If a question is not about the festival/event, politely inform the user that you are tuned to only answer questions about the ABCD festival. This is crucial for our startup.

{context}

User's Question: {question}
"""

PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=[
                        'context', 'question', 'query_language'])
chat = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever, verbose=constants.MODEL_VERBOSE, chain_type_kwargs={
        "prompt": PROMPT,
        "verbose": constants.MODEL_VERBOSE
    },)


result = chat({"query": text})
```

Problems are:

1. The llm sometimes gives answers from it's own knowledge and not from the context.
2. The llm also sometimes answers in English even if the user has asked the question in Arabic.

How do I solve both the issues. Can someone please help me optimize the prompt and the code if I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this prompt, this should resolve your problems

Code

```
llm = VertexAI(
model_name="text-bison@001",
max_output_tokens=250, # Reduced to focus on relevancy
temperature=0.2, # Low temperature to maintain context
verbose=False # Set to False for less verbose, more focused responses
)
"""You are an Arabic chatbot assistant specializing in providing information about the 'Anybody Can Dance Festival'. Your responses should be strictly within the context of the festival. Use language detection to ensure you respond in the same language as the user's question. If the question is in Arabic, respond in Arabic; if it is in English, respond in English. If you don't know the answer, state that you don't know and do not provide unrelated information.

Context: {context}

User's Question in [Arabic/English]: {question}"""
```

Comment: no it's not an arabic chabot only. The chatbot converses in English and Arabic. If the question asked is in English, then the bot should reply in English only. But if the question is asked in Arabic, then it should give response in Arabic.

Comment: Also, I have seen sometimes the llm model gives answers out of context. It makes things up. Can you cite any reasons why it does thay ?

Comment: added more details in answer, please try and let me know

Comment: No, it's not working. When I just query: "Hi". It tries to complete the sentence first and then gives the answer.

Comment: this is not working.